# Is there a way to use java.util.Preferences under Windows without it using the Registry as the backend?

Tags: java, windows, registry, preferences

I want to use the java.util.Preferences API but I don't want my program to attempt to read or write to the Windows registry. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I trust you have read the [read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/readwrite-to-windows-registry-using-java) and you then want to have another back-end than the registry when using the `java.util.Preferences` API

You could extend the [`Preference` API](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_preferences_api), like [Bernhard](http://www.jroller.com/berni/entry/my_preferences) or [Croft](https://github.com/eis/simple-suomi24-java-client/tree/master/src/main/java/net/infotrek/util/prefs) did, as described in [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/preferences/):

> Because the [Preferences API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) is back-end neutral, you need not care whether the data are stored in files, database tables, or a platform-specific storage such as the Windows Registry.

Examples of extensions through [new `Preferences` can be seen here](http://code.ohloh.net/search?s=%22java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences%22&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&filterChecked=true).

That is better, IMO, than to use another API.

---

For instance, searching for classes extending [`java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/AbstractPreferences.html):

- You can use a preference store backed by an XML file:

[`de.unika.ipd.grgen.util.MyPreferences`](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=cuJKx0oHXYyFIRciM_dbHYvZ4FU&cid=GPBRWJBaRz4&s=%22java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences%22&fp=287105&mp&projSelected=true#L0)

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences;
import java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException;

/**
 * Own implementation of the Java preferences API, that does not use
 * a "OS backing store" but relies on importing and exporting the
 * preferences via xml files.
 * Also, If a preference is got, but was not in the tree, it is entered.
 */
public class MyPreferences extends AbstractPreferences {

    private Map<String, String> prefs = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, AbstractPreferences> children = new HashMap<String, AbstractPreferences>();

  public MyPreferences(MyPreferences parent, String name) {
    super(parent, name);
  }

  /**
   * @see java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences#putSpi(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
   */
  protected void putSpi(String key, String value) {
    prefs.put(key, value);
  }
```

---

- Or you could store those preferences in an LDAP:

[`de.tarent.ldap.prefs.LDAPSystemPreferences`](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=adcrwCk6yHdkEjb9jbpCxtI4bZg&cid=HrFBgz21-IE&s=%22java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences%22%20factory&fp=9551&mp&projSelected=true#L0)

```java
import java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences;
import java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;

import de.tarent.ldap.LDAPException;
import de.tarent.ldap.LDAPManager;

/**
 * @author kirchner
 * 
 * Preferences im LDAP
 */
public class LDAPSystemPreferences extends AbstractPreferences {
    LDAPManager     ldm         = null;
    Properties      properties  = new Properties();
    //Map für key/value der Preferences
    Map             cache       = new HashMap();
    //Map für timestamp der Preferences
    Map             timestamp   = new HashMap();
    private Boolean deleted     = Boolean.FALSE;
```

---

- Or you can use a simple property file:

`com.adito.boot.PropertyPreferences`:

```java
import java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences;
import java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;


/**
 * A simple implementation for the preferences API. That stores preferences
 * in propery files. We do not have to worry about sharing the preferencese 
 * with other JVM instance so there is no need for any kind of synchronising
 * or locking.
 */
public class PropertyPreferences extends AbstractPreferences {
```

Comment: Good stuff, thanks. Note that you can se the PreferencesFactory to be used with the Java system property "java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory". http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/synd/2001/10/17/j2se.html?page=2

Comment: Cool, In the mean time I also found a nice public domain property file based one here: http://www.davidc.net/programming/java/java-preferences-using-file-backing-store  I wound up using this because Mavericks seems to have introduced some weirdness in the default implementation. I found the default backing store file in $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist and although binary I was still able to cat it. I observed data written by my program, and then observed it disappearing from the file with no further interaction. The default store seems broken on OSX Mavericks.

Answer (score 4):

It is always possible to extend java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.

An alternative could be to use The [Configuration package](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) of Apache Commons allows you to read and write configuration data from/to different sources.