# I'm trying to use Java Preferences from XML WITHOUT using Windows registry, but I see a Registry-related message

Tags: java, registry, preferences

I have a simplified program that produces the following output, in which the lines starting with ^ are generated by my code. Note that I deliberately deleted the Prefs key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft.

```
^ A preferences file was found
Aug 09, 2013 2:45:23 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002.
Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
^ doallunconditionally: false
^ footnotespopup: false
^ thumbnailsgenerated: true
^ thumbnailwidth: 200
^ pathin: C:/Users/Das/Google Drive
^ pathout: C:/Users/Das/ottmar/site
^ pathlog: C:/Users/Das/ottmar/logs
```

My question is, can I bypass the registry entirely? I thought I should be able to.
I can post the source code (180 lines) if needed.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a perfectly valid question. Are you using windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually discovered a workaround (not a solution) to this problem.  As I stated before, I had inadvertently/foolishly deleted the `Prefs` node in `Software\JavaSoft` in the Registry, and when I recreated it the message went away.

I now assume that the Windows registry *is* used whether you like it or not.

Answer (score 0):

This page explains how to use a preferences store apart from the Windows registry:

http://www.davidc.net/programming/java/java-preferences-using-file-backing-store

I've not tried it but it seems to be fairly straightforward. You can also checkout:

[Is there a way to use java.util.Preferences under Windows without it using the Registry as the backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208231/is-there-a-way-to-use-java-util-preferences-under-windows-without-it-using-the-r?rq=1)